# which is very useful service to reduce the cost when hosting static website in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I analyse the costing for S3 GET request and Cloudfront Cost, but I can't take correct decision because I don't have enough knowledge about AWS transfer cost,
We can host a static website in aws using S3, Route53, with or without cloudfront.
cloudfront for content delivery from all edge location . really cloudfront improves performance for static content . my question is can we reduce the cost for static hosting using cloudfront? If performance and latency is not important thing , then how to reduce the cost for static website hosting?

Comment: How much traffic you are expecting for your static website?

Comment: daily 500+ users will visit my website in india only , But  I am only focussing to reduce the cost.

Comment: S3 and CloudFront are the best services to provide high availability and scalability. You can check your cost here: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Comment: I know these two are best ? but I need to know which is low ? performance and latency not important . compare them with their cost only

Comment: Above calculator need data transfer , but I mention earlier , I don't have enough knowledge about data transfer

Comment: Data transfer out is how much data is transferred from the CloudFront or S3. Example there a home page consists of one HTML file, 1 CSS file whose size id 1KB each. So whenever someone requests home page you will have data transfer cost of 2KB.

Comment: Images which were loaded in html page ?

Comment: Yes if they are stored in s3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165711/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-naveen-kerati).

Comment: so you are telling We can save cost without using cloudfront in static website hosting in aws . AM I right ?